# reference for "wonderful compactification"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

I am trying to learn about the wonderful compactification for (adjoint) semi-simple groups. Are there any good references that sketch out the full construction other than here: http://arxiv.org/abs/0801.0456? (and the original De Concini Procesi papers)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know of two more references, but I'm not an expert in the topic, so I don't know how good they will be for you:

1. [Section II.7](http://doi.org/10.1007/0-8176-4466-0_8) in Borel–Ji's *[Compactifications of Symmetric and Locally Symmetric Spaces](http://doi.org/10.1007/0-8176-4466-0)* discusses the construction, but it is really just an outline that refers to the de Concini–Procesi paper.
2. [Chapter 6](http://doi.org/10.1007/0-8176-4405-9_6) in Brion–Kumar's *[Frobenius Splitting Methods in Geometry and Representation Theory](http://doi.org/10.1007/b137486)* gives proofs that are written so that the construction works in positive characteristic. I don't recall if that made the proofs more complicated or not. It's probably also worth looking at the references in that chapter, especially in the comments section 6.C.

Comment: Thanks, Brion's book seems good..